# Calling symbol from .so

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries

I have an .so library, and run `nm -gC` on it.

I see an output like this:

```
0011a011 W void my_fun< unsigned char>(unsigned char*, unsigned char, int)
```

None of the headers that I can include contain this function, but I'd like to call it from my cpp file.

How would I go about doing it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> None of the headers that I can include contain this function,

From the [nm man page](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/nm.html):

> W
>
> w
>
> The symbol is a weak symbol that has not been specifically tagged as a weak object symbol.

So it's a weak symbol. If none of the header files declare it, then it may not be defined. You might still try to declare it yourself and call it in case it is (you'll need to link against the library):

```
void my_fun(unsigned char*, unsigned char, int);

// ...

my_fun(foo, bar, baz);
```

If this is a C++ function, then you **can not** use the `dlopen()` API in a portable manner.

Comment: There's no `u`, though, so I think the symbol is in fact defined. It would just be overridden if linked against another symbol of the same name.

Answer (score 4):

1. Load the library with [`dlopen(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen)
2. Get the function's address with [`dlsym(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen), and cast it to a function pointer of the appropriate type
3. Call the function
4. When you're all done, close the library with [`dlclose(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen)

Comment: And what about name mangling? This is a C++ function (at least it really is likely to be one, since `nm` can extract type information).

Comment: @H2CO3 that's why you can use `extern c`. Assuming you are the one wrote `my_fun` and It doesn't use classes and c++ features (life sometimes are vicious).

Comment: @0x90 If the symbol is already compiled as mangled, then `extern "C"` won't help.

Comment: @H2CO3: If it's a C++ function, you can still open it by its mangled name.  Of course, doing that ties you to a particular compiler and many other details, so it's very non-portable and not recommended, but it *can* be done.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield Certainly, I don't doubt the possibility. (If you see me around answering questions, you surely note it's usually me who break the "it's impossible" myth.) I'm just saying it's generally undesirable (except for debugging, hacking on a compiler, etc. but that counts as very narrow for me.)

Answer (score 1):

Meet your new [friends](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen):

```
void *dlopen(const char *filename, int flag);

char *dlerror(void);

void *dlsym(void *handle, const char *symbol);

int dlclose(void *handle);
```

[wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_loading#In_C.2FC.2B.2B) summarizes the most platforms dynamic library loading mechanisms I use it all the times.

---

```
g++ -shared -fPIC myProgram.cpp -o libmyprogram.so
```

that will compile `myProgram.cpp` as `.so`, if you would like to [use it](http://www.isotton.com/devel/docs/C++-dlopen-mini-HOWTO/C++-dlopen-mini-HOWTO.html) with `main.cpp`:

```
g++ main.cpp -L. -lmyProgram
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just declare the method

```
void my_fun(unsigned char*, unsigned char, int);
```

and then try to use/call it. Basically, create your own (implicit) header for it. Of course it will depend on the symbol being defined in your library.